# Topology of 3D rotations

Tags: rotations, topological-groups, spheres

[Wikipedia chapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Topology) about topology of 3D rotation group says:

> Consider the solid ball in $\mathbb {R} ^{3}$ of radius $\pi$ (that is, all points of $\mathbb{R} ^{3}$ of distance $\pi$ or less from the
> origin). Given the above, for every point in this ball there is a
> rotation, with axis through the point and the origin, **and rotation angle equal to the distance of the point from the origin. The identity rotation corresponds to the point at the center of the ball.**

followed by:

> consider the path running from the "north pole" straight through the
> interior down to the south pole [...] this loop represents a
> continuous sequence of rotations about the z-axis **starting and ending at the identity rotation** (i.e. a series of rotation through an angle $\varphi$
> where $\varphi$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$).

I do not understand why "north pole" (and also south pole) is the identity rotation. As north pole has cartessian coordinates $(0,0,\pi)$, according to first paragraph it must be understood as a rotation around z axis by a rotation angle $\pi$, that is not the identity rotation.

Could be due to this misunderstood, I do not reach my true target, understand why rotations has a fundamental group of order $2$.

Comment: You forgot "...and rotation angle equal to the distance of the point from the origin. The identity rotation corresponds to the point at the center of the ball." I wouldn't over think it too much, the idea is that the path is a loop, start the path at the origin, go up to the north pole (which is identified with the south pole) then up to the origin. I.E. it is not important where the loop "starts" since it is a loop.

Comment: @RyanK: citation extended to include the phrase you mean. Now, according to wiki, there are 3 points that maps to identity: north pole, center and south pole.

Comment: I agree the wording is a little confusing, just think the path starts at the origin. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The north pole is a clockwise rotation with angle $\pi$ and the south pole is a counterclockwise rotation with angle $\pi$. But these are equal (since the angle is $\pi$; otherwise, they would be two distinct rotations). And, while you go from the north pole to the south pole through the center of the sphere, you pass throuh that center, which corresponds to the identity rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that north pole and south pole are the same rotation in this model, but not the identity rotation as wiki seems to say.

Comment: Yes, they are not the identity rotation; they are half-turns. It's the center of the sphere and only that point that corresponds to the identity rotation. On the other hand, it is clear to me that whoever wrote that passage never meant to identify the poles with the identity rotation.

Comment: We are talking about a loop here. It doesn't have an initial and a final point. Although I agree that that passage is written in such a way that it seems that the poles correspond to the identity rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the center of the ball – and no other point – represents the identity rotation (that is, no rotation at all).

You can find some interesting pictures, and a free PC program, that graphically illustrate the axis-angle way of specifying rotation space by searching on “dirac string trick”.